# Resample trajectory to have equal euclidean distance in each sample

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, resampling

Let's say we have a list of x,y points:

```py
x = [0, 0, 0]
y = [0, 10, 100]
```

The Euclidean distance between points is now [10, 90].
I'm looking for a function that accepts x, y and the sample_rate, and could output equal distance points. e.g.:

```py
x = [0, 0, 0]
y = [0, 10, 100]

resample_distance = 10
resampler(x, y, resample_distance)
# Outputs:
# [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Using an similiar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19118653/3686236), we can achieve almost correct values, but that's not accurate:

```py
resample_trajectory_same_distance(data[0], data[1], 10)
# Output:
# [ 0.        , 10.27027027, 20.81081081, 31.08108108, 41.62162162, 51.89189189, 62.43243243, 72.7027027 , 83.24324324, 93.78378378]
# [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
```

Using any 3rd party libs like numpy, scipy, etc is OK.

Comment: The euclidean distance is ((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2)**0.5

Comment: All points at the same distance define a circle and as such the question is not well-posed.

Comment: @flabons Euclidean distance can be used in any dimensions. I don't understand why you are saying question is not well-posed, can you give some hints ? imo the question is clear

Comment: @flabons Probably author meant not to find such points that are all at equal distance to each other, but to find such N points that each two neighoboring `(x[i], y[i])` and `(x[i + 1], y[i + 1])` have same given distance between each other. And to find such N points so that they lie on interpolation function of original points.

Comment: @JafarAkhondali BTW, resampling data means that we need to choose some interpolation function, e.g. linear/quadratic/cubic or some other. Because depending on choice resampled points will be different. Do you know what interpolation function type you need? Or just any quite accurate type?

Comment: @Arty Any accurate type is fine

Comment: How would you cope with a zigzag function? Something like e.g. `x = [0, 10, 0.1, 10.1, 0.2, 10.2]; y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. A problem to obtain a rigorous mathematical definition is that points further along the curve might be closer in euclidean distance.

Comment: @JafarAkhondali I spent quite a lot of time today implementing [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64684587/941531), I implemented quite advanced algorithm that does Cubic Splines Interpolation (with all math/formulas inside my code) plus Binary Search Algorithm in order to find Euclidean Equal Distance points that you need in your task, plus all is boosted significantly by Numba compiler/optimizer. Please take a look at my answer/post. All algorithms are located inside meaning that it doesn't depend on any scientific libraries just on these two: `python -m pip install numpy numba`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented next solution.

All functions for efficiency are compiled by [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) compiler/optimizer supporting [Just-in-Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)/[Ahead-of-Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) technologies. Numba converts all marked by `@numba.njit` decorator functions to pure [C/C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) code automatically on the fly whenever Python code is started, then C++ code is compiled to machine code. No interaction with Python is done in such functions, only low-level fast structures are used inside. Hence Numba usually is able to increase speed of almost any code by factor of `50x`-`200x` times on average, very fast! Such Python compiled code usually achieves speed very near to speed of same algorithms implemented by hand in pure C/C++. To use Numba one just needs to install just two next python packages: `python -m pip install numpy numba`.

Next steps are done in my code:

1. Input function is represented by two 1D arrays `x` and `y`.
2. Input function (points) is then [Approximated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_approximation) (or called differently as [Interpolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)) by one of two types of piece-wise functions - 1) [Linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) 2) [Cubic Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).
3. Linear piece-wise approximation function just connects given array of points `(x0, y0)` so that pair of two consecutive points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` are connected by straight line (segment).
4. Cubic Spline is more advanced way of smoothly approximating function, it connects all points `(x0, y0)` so that each pair of points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` is connected by cubic segment represented by [cubic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) so that it goes through these two end-points plus first and second derivative of adjacent segments within common point are equal, these all ensures that function looks very smooth and nice, and is very popular in computer graphics for doing natural/realistic approximation/visualization of functions/surfaces.
5. Then using very fast [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) I'm searching one-by-one for points on this Interpolation function, points such that [Euclidean Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) between each two consecutive points equals exactly to desired (provided to algorithm) value `d`.
6. All above is just computational part. The rest of steps does visualizing part, drawing plots using `matplotlib` library. Detailed description of plots goes after code right before plots.

In order to use this implemented Euclidean Equal-Distance Resampling algorithm you need just to `import` my next script-module and do `xr, yr = module_name.resample_euclid_equidist(x, y, dist)` where input and output `x` and `y` are both 1D numpy arrays with floating point numbers, this will return input points resampled at `dist` euclidean distance. More examples of usage are located in my code's `test()` function. Very first run is quite slow (can take around `15` seconds), this run is just a compilation run, all my code is automatically precompiled to C/C++ and then machine code, next runs are very fast, especially resampling function itself just takes some milliseconds. Also to use just computational part of code you need to install `python -m pip install numpy numba`, and to run whole of my code including tests and visualization (just run my script) you need to install `python -m pip install numpy numba matplotlib` just one time.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64441803#main.py)

```
# Needs:
#     For computation: python -m pip install numpy numba
#     For testing:     python -m pip install matplotlib

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Compiling...', flush = True)
    
import numba, numpy as np

# Linear Approximator related functions

# Spline value calculating function, given params and "x"
@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def func_linear(x, ix, x0, y0, k):
    return (x - x0[ix]) * k[ix] + y0[ix]
    
# Compute piece-wise linear function for "x" out of sorted "x0" points
@numba.njit([f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def piece_wise_linear(x, x0, y0, k, dummy0, dummy1):
    xsh = x.shape
    x = x.ravel()
    ix = np.searchsorted(x0[1 : -1], x)
    y = func_linear(x, ix, x0, y0, k)
    y = y.reshape(xsh)
    return y
    
# Spline Approximator related functions
    
# Solves linear system given by Tridiagonal Matrix
# Helper for calculating cubic splines
@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def tri_diag_solve(A, B, C, F):
    n = B.size
    assert A.ndim == B.ndim == C.ndim == F.ndim == 1 and (
        A.size == B.size == C.size == F.size == n
    ) #, (A.shape, B.shape, C.shape, F.shape)
    Bs, Fs = np.zeros_like(B), np.zeros_like(F)
    Bs[0], Fs[0] = B[0], F[0]
    for i in range(1, n):
        Bs[i] = B[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * C[i - 1]
        Fs[i] = F[i] - A[i] / Bs[i - 1] * Fs[i - 1]
    x = np.zeros_like(B)
    x[-1] = Fs[-1] / Bs[-1]
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        x[i] = (Fs[i] - C[i] * x[i + 1]) / Bs[i]
    return x
    
# Calculate cubic spline params
@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def calc_spline_params(x, y):
    a = y
    h = np.diff(x)
    c = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,), dtype = y.dtype),
        np.append(tri_diag_solve(h[:-1], (h[:-1] + h[1:]) * 2, h[1:],
        ((a[2:] - a[1:-1]) / h[1:] - (a[1:-1] - a[:-2]) / h[:-1]) * 3), 0)))
    d = np.diff(c) / (3 * h)
    b = (a[1:] - a[:-1]) / h + (2 * c[1:] + c[:-1]) / 3 * h
    return a[1:], b, c[1:], d
    
# Spline value calculating function, given params and "x"
@numba.njit(cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d):
    dx = x - x0[1:][ix]
    return a[ix] + (b[ix] + (c[ix] + d[ix] * dx) * dx) * dx
    
# Compute piece-wise spline function for "x" out of sorted "x0" points
@numba.njit([f'f{ii}[:](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True, inline = 'always')
def piece_wise_spline(x, x0, a, b, c, d):
    xsh = x.shape
    x = x.ravel()
    ix = np.searchsorted(x0[1 : -1], x)
    y = func_spline(x, ix, x0, a, b, c, d)
    y = y.reshape(xsh)
    return y
    
# Appximates function given by (x0, y0) by piece-wise spline or linear
def approx_func(x0, y0, t = 'spline'): # t is spline/linear
    assert x0.ndim == 1 and y0.ndim == 1 and x0.size == y0.size#, (x0.shape, y0.shape)
    n = x0.size - 1
    if t == 'linear':
        k = np.diff(y0) / np.diff(x0)
        return piece_wise_linear, (x0, y0, k, np.zeros((0,), dtype = y0.dtype), np.zeros((0,), dtype = y0.dtype))
    elif t == 'spline':
        a, b, c, d = calc_spline_params(x0, y0)
        return piece_wise_spline, (x0, a, b, c, d)
    else:
        assert False, t

# Main function that computes Euclidian Equi-Distant points based on approximation function
@numba.njit(
    [f'f{ii}[:, :](f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}, b1, b1, f{ii}, f{ii}, f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:], f{ii}[:])' for ii in (4, 8)],
    cache = True, fastmath = True)
def _resample_inner(x, y, d, is_spline, strict, aerr, rerr, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4):
    rs, r = 0, np.zeros((1 << 10, 2), dtype = y.dtype)
    t0 = np.zeros((1,), dtype = y.dtype)
    i, x0, y0 = 0, x[0], y[0]
    #print(i, x0, y0, np.sin(x0))
    while True:
        if rs >= r.size:
            r = np.concatenate((r, np.zeros(r.shape, dtype = r.dtype))) # Grow array
        r[rs, 0] = x0
        r[rs, 1] = y0
        rs += 1
        if i + 1 >= x.size:
            break
        ie = min(i + 1 + np.searchsorted(x[i + 1:], x0 + d), x.size - 1)
        for ie in range(i + 1 if strict else ie, ie + 1):
            xl = max(x0, x[ie - 1 if strict else i])
            xr = max(x0, x[ie])
            # Do binary search to find next point
            for ii in range(1000):
                if xr - xl <= aerr:
                    break # Already very small delta X interval
                xm = (xl + xr) / 2
                t0[0] = xm
                if is_spline:
                    ym = piece_wise_spline(t0, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)[0]
                else:
                    ym = piece_wise_linear(t0, a0, a1, a2, a3, a4)[0]
                
                # Compute Euclidian distance
                dx_, dy_ = xm - x0, ym - y0
                dm = np.sqrt(dx_ * dx_ + dy_ * dy_)

                if -rerr <= dm / d - 1. <= rerr:
                    break # We got d with enough precision
                if dm >= d:
                    xr = xm
                else:
                    xl = xm
            else:
                assert False # To many iterations
            if -rerr <= dm / d - 1. <= rerr:
                break # Next point found
        else:
            break # No next point found, we're finished
        i = np.searchsorted(x, xm) - 1
        #print('_0', i, x0, y0, np.sin(x0), dist(x0, xm, y0, ym), dist(x0, xm, np.sin(x0), np.sin(xm)))
        x0, y0 = xm, ym
        #print('_1', i, x0, y0, np.sin(x0), dm)
    return r[:rs]
    
# Resamples (x, y) points using given approximation function type
# so that euclidian distance between each resampled points equals to "d".
# If strict = True then strictly closest (by X) next point at distance "d"
# is chosen, which can imply more computations, when strict = False then
# any found point with distance "d" is taken as next.
def resample_euclid_equidist(
    x, y, d, *,
    aerr = 2 ** -21, rerr = 2 ** -9, approx = 'spline',
    return_approx = False, strict = True,
):
    assert d > 0, d
    dtype = np.dtype(y.dtype).type
    x, y, d, aerr, rerr = [dtype(e) for e in [x, y, d, aerr, rerr]]
    ixs = np.argsort(x)
    x, y = x[ixs], y[ixs]
    f, fargs = approx_func(x, y, approx)
    r = _resample_inner(x, y, d, approx == 'spline', strict, aerr, rerr, *fargs)
    return (r[:, 0], r[:, 1]) + ((), (lambda x: f(x, *fargs),))[return_approx]

def test():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np, time
    np.random.seed(0)
    # Input
    n = 50
    x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(0., 10 * np.pi, (n,)))
    y = np.sin(x) * 5 + np.sin(1 + 2.5 * x) * 3 + np.sin(2 + 0.5 * x) * 2
    # Visualize
    for isl, sl in enumerate(['spline', 'linear']):
        # Compute resampled points
        for i in range(3):
            tb = time.time()
            xa, ya, fa = resample_euclid_equidist(x, y, 1.5, approx = sl, return_approx = True)
            print(sl, 'try', i, 'run time', round(time.time() - tb, 4), 'sec', flush = True)
        # Compute spline/linear approx points
        fax = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 1000)
        fay = fa(fax)
        # Plotting
        plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (9.6, 5.4)
        for ci, (cx, cy, fn) in enumerate([
            (x, y, 'original'), (fax, fay, f'approx_{sl}'), (xa, ya, 'euclid_euqidist'),
        ]):
            p, = plt.plot(cx, cy)
            p.set_label(fn)
            if ci >= 2:
                plt.scatter(cx, cy, marker = '.', color = p.get_color())
                if False:
                    # Show distances
                    def dist(x0, x1, y0, y1):
                        # Compute Euclidian distance
                        dx, dy = x1 - x0, y1 - y0
                        return np.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
                    for i in range(cx.size - 1):
                        plt.annotate(
                            round(dist(cx[i], cx[i + 1], cy[i], cy[i + 1]), 2),
                            (cx[i], cy[i]), fontsize = 'xx-small',
                        )
        plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable = 'box')
        plt.legend()
        plt.show()
        plt.clf()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Below are resulting plots. As an example function is taken `y = np.sin(x) * 5 + np.sin(1 + 2.5 * x) * 3 + np.sin(2 + 0.5 * x) * 2` sampled at `50` uniformly random points for `0 <= x <= 10 * pi` range. Plots: `blue` is original function, connected with straight line points, `orange` is approximation function (spline or linear) this is just interpolating function, it is drawn as hundreds of points that's why looks smooth, `green` is resulting Euclidian-Equal-Distance points, exactly what was task about, euclidian length of each segment between two green small circles is equal exactly to desired distance `d`. First screen represents approximation by piece-wise cubic spline. Second screen represents approximation for by piece-wise linear function for exactly same input points.

Spline:

[image: spline]

Linear:

[image: linear]

Comment: I used this code on my 2D positional data and it did an awesome job of maintaining the shape of the curve and creating equidistant points - however it changed the range of my x values. The original range was from -15 to + 15 but after using your code it became -15 to +2.9. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: also if there are duplicate values in the array, it breaks because of division by zero.

Comment: @CentauriAurelius Can you provide a minimal example of few points when x values have changed? I need some data to test and debug my algorithm. Regarding second question - it can be easily solved by removing duplicates in the beginning of my algorithm.

Comment: @CentauriAurelius Have you tried plotting results before and after using my function? Same plot like I did in my answer. Because in my case input X was in range [1;30] and output X was in same range. To figure out what's wrong in your case I need to see minimal example of input data, can you provide?

Answer (score 0):

As many comments have pointed out, you need to be more specific on how you want to handle ambiguous cases. In your example  `x = [0, 0, 0]; y = [0, 10, 100]` the values add up neatly as they are multiples of 10. But you need to determine yourself how you want to handle the cases when the values do not add up neatly.

I've written a function that can return a the x and y values of all points a given distance (`resample_distance`) from each other between 2 points, starting from the first. Maybe this can be of use to you as a basis to build on top.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def resampler_2_points(p1, p2, resample_distance, include_endpoint=False):
    # get the distacne between the points
    distance_p1p2 = np.sqrt(  np.sum( (p2 - p1)**2 ) )
    
    # check for invalid cases
    if resample_distance > distance_p1p2:
        print("Resample distance larger than distance between points")
        return None
    
    elif distance_p1p2 == 0:
        print("Distance between the two points is 0")
        return None
    
    # if all is okay
    else:
        # get the stepsize of x and y coordinates
        stepsize_x, stepsize_y = (p2 - p1) * (resample_distance / distance_p1p2)
        
        # handle the case when a 'stepsize' along and axis equals 0  
        if stepsize_x == 0:
            y = np.arange(p1[1], p2[1], stepsize_y)
            x = np.zeros(len(y)) + p1[0]
        
        elif stepsize_y == 0:
            x = np.arange(p1[0], p2[0], stepsize_x)
            y = np.zeros(len(x)) + p1[1]
            
        # all other cases
        else:
            
            x = np.arange(p1[0], p2[0], stepsize_x)
            y = np.arange(p1[1], p2[1], stepsize_y)    
          
        # optionally append endpoint to final list
        if include_endpoint:
            x = np.append(x, p2[0])
            y = np.append(y, p2[1])
        
        # retrun the x and y coordinates in two arrays
        return x, y
```

And below is an example use of this function wit the output plot.

```
# set values (x and y coordiantes) for 2 points, and an resample distance
p1 = np.array([2,3])
p2 = np.array([20,15])
resample_distance = 4
x, y = resampler_2_points(p1, p2, resample_distance, include_endpoint=False)

plt.plot(x,y, 'o--r', label="Sampled points")
plt.scatter([p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]], s=100, c='b', label="Input points")
plt.ylim((0,25))
plt.xlim((0,25))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]